# htaccess remove php extension does not work properly

Tags: php, file, .htaccess

There are lots of codes out there which are working but not properly.
When I use those codes and remove the (.php) from my nav bar (home instead of home.php) all the sitemaps generators are counting the links double.

```
example:

home.php
home
contact.php
contact
```

They see the files and the links.
So what I need is that the htaccess is removing the (.php) without that I have to remove it from the link code.

I hope that my answer is clear and understandable! :)

Comment: Yeah, you need to replace all the links in your script with home and contact instead of contact.php and home.php

Comment: You need to do a little more reading http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me too Struck with the same problem. I found the solution with the following code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```